# How to customize the style of the vimeo subtitles?

Tags: customization, vimeo, subtitle

I'm trying to remove the black background on the vimeo subtitles.

[image: vimeo player]

I added some css to override the default styles but it seems to ignore it.

```
.player .vp-captions>span {
    background: transparent !important;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Subtitles on video and on other video players come from a .VTT .ASS or .SRT file. The kinds of look like this.

```
1
00:02:26,407 --> 00:02:31,356  X1:100 X2:100 Y1:100 Y2:100
<font color="#00ff00">Detta handlar om min storebrors</font> 
<b><i><u>kriminella beteende och foersvinnade.</u></i></b>

2
00:02:31,567 --> 00:02:37,164 
Vi talar inte laengre om Wade. Det aer 
som om han aldrig hade existerat.
```

I doubt you will be able to style the subtitle file programmatically from Vimeo API, altho you could pull the subtitle files and rewrite them with your own style.

That being said, if you are playing the video in a html5 player, you could override the styles.

Lots of content creators like to burn them into the video itself using simple online video editors